# I'm trying make it so when .toggle-menu is clicked the data-target get a class toggled and other div expand off

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying make it so when `.toggle-menu` is clicked the `data-target` get a class toggled and other `div` expand off.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
  
  if (windowWidth <= 768)
    jQuery('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');

  jQuery('.toggle-menu').click(function() {
    // get this data-target
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $(target).toggleClass('in');
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.col .collapse.in {
  display: block;
}

.col .collapse {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <div class="day-header">
    <h4><a class="toggle-menu" data-target="#foot">Footwere</a></h4>
  </div>
  <div id="foot" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <p>
      Show footwere
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <div class="day-header">
    <h4><a class="toggle-menu" data-target="#cloth">cloths</a></h4>
  </div>
  <div id="cloth" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <p>
      Show cloth
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the ones that have `.in` already (where `.in` are being shown) and remove the class.  As you want to toggle the one being clicked, you need to exclude it when removing from the others:

```
$(".in").not(target).removeClass("in");
```

Updated fiddle:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
  if (windowWidth <= 768)
    jQuery('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');

  jQuery('.toggle-menu').click(function() {
    // get this data-target
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $(".in").not(target).removeClass("in");
    $(target).toggleClass('in');
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.col .collapse.in {
  display: block;
}

.col .collapse {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <div class="day-header">
    <h4><a class="toggle-menu" data-target="#foot">Footwere</a></h4>
  </div>

  <div id="foot" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <p>
      Show footwere
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <div class="day-header">
    <h4><a class="toggle-menu" data-target="#cloth">cloths</a></h4>
  </div>
  <div id="cloth" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <p>
      Show cloth
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**: with a basic plus/minus that toggles

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
  if (windowWidth <= 768) {
    jQuery('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');
    $(".plus,.minus").toggle();
  }

  jQuery('.toggle-menu').click(function() {
    // get this data-target
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $(".in").not(target).removeClass("in");
    $(target).toggleClass('in');
    $(this).closest(".day-header").find(".plus,.minus").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.col .collapse.in {
  display: block;
}

.col .collapse {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <div class="day-header">
    <h4>
      <span class='plus' style='display:none;'>+</span>
      <span class='minus'>-</span>
      <a class="toggle-menu" data-target="#foot">Footware</a>
    </h4>
  </div>

  <div id="foot" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <p>
      Show footware
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <div class="day-header">
    <h4>
      <span class='plus' style='display:none;'>+</span>
      <span class='minus'>-</span>
      <a class="toggle-menu" data-target="#cloth">cloths</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="cloth" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <p>
      Show cloth
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You so much.Can you please tell me how can I add Pulse minus sign when expand and collapse.